# php pagination class first try

Tags: php, class, pagination

I'm trying to make a pagination class, this is my first attempt to make a real php class, besides all those basic oop class tutorials, you know those with some calculations.

What I really want is someone to look it through and tell me what's good practice and what's bad practice, some I can avoid getting some bad habits :).. and maybe some pointers in how I can devolop it further..

The class looks like this at the momment:

```
class Pagination {


public $db = NULL;      // Get the DB
public $sqlQuery;       // Get the sql string
public $per_page;       // Get rows per page
public $total_results;  // Get total results

public $total_pages;
public $p;
public $pages;
public $rows;
public $pagination;
public $url;

public function __construct($per_page,$sqlQuery,$db){
    $this->per_page = $per_page;
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->sqlQuery = $sqlQuery;
    $this->total_results = $this->db->query($this->sqlQuery)->num_rows;
    $this->p = $p = NULL;

    $this->url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // Makes sure we have a offset point
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
        $this->p = $_GET['p'];
    }else{
        $this->p = 1;
    }

    // Get the amount of pages..
    $this->total_pages = ceil($this->total_results/$this->per_page);

    // Make sure we can't get false value, 0 or negative
    if($this->p < 1){

        $this->p = 1;
    }

    // Make sure property $p can't be higher than or max pages
    if($this->p > $this->total_pages){
        $this->p = $this->total_pages;
    }

    $limit = $this->p * $this->per_page;

    $offset = $limit - $this->per_page;

    $this->sqlQuery .= " limit ".$offset.",".$this->per_page; // possible error

    $this->rows = $this->db->query($this->sqlQuery);

}
// Constructer ends


public function getResult(){
    return $this->rows;
}

public function getPagination(){


    $path = preg_replace("/&p=".$this->p."/","",$this->url);

    $this->pagination = "";

    if($this->p != 1){
        $this->pagination .= "<a href='".$path."&p=1'>&laquo;</a>&nbsp;";
        $previous = $this->p-1;
        $this->pagination .= "<a href='".$path."&p=".$previous."'>Forrige</a>&nbsp;";       
    };
        $range = 3;
    //for($i=1;$i<=$this->total_pages;$i++){
     for($i= ($this->p - $range); $i < (($this->p + $range) + 1); $i++){

        if (($i > 0) && ($i <= $this->total_pages)) {

            if($i == $this->p){

                $this->pagination .= "<span>".$i."</span>&nbsp;";
            }else{

                $this->pagination .= "<a href='".$path."&p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;";
            };
        };

    };

    if($this->p != $this->total_pages){
        $next = $this->p + 1;
        $this->pagination .= "<a href='".$path."&p=".$next."'>N&aelig;ste</a>&nbsp;";
        $this->pagination .= "<a href='".$path."&p=".$this->total_pages."'>&raquo;</a>";
    };

    return $this->pagination;
}

}
```

I know that the properby $this->url won't work in a secure http request, just don't know how to fix it at the time being.

Here's a simple call:

```
        $db = db::getInstance();

    $sqlQuery = "select * from movies order by name asc";
    $result = new Pagination(5, $sqlQuery, $db);

    $rows = $result->getResult();
    $pagination = $result->getPagination();

    $this->registry->template->rows = $rows;
    $this->registry->template->pagination = $pagination;

    $this->registry->template->show("movies_index");
```

Any pointers would be helpful :)

Comment: without read the whole code, just one simply question: why all class members are declared `public`?

Comment: My main comment: this class does *far* too much. Database interaction, outputting content, pagination calculation... You really should have multiple, decoupled classes here.

Comment: This question appears to be more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You could just query the SQL once, and hang onto the results, without re-querying again

Comment: so i could fetch my rows and simply remove the db from the class? something like that ?